# Why props is undefined inside addEventListener function in React

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener

I have following code:

```
const useMousePlayerMove = ({ playerMe }: any) => { 
    console.log({playerMe}) // exist
    const handleCardMove = useCallback((event: any) => {
        console.log(playerMe); // undefined
    }, [playerMe]);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleCardMove);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleCardMove);
    }, []);

    return null;
};
```

There is a variable `playerMe` (it is object). In `console.log` I can see that it is really exist.

Once `handleCardMove` is fired, `playerMe` inside function is `undefined`.

Why?

Same without `useCallback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const useMousePlayerMove = ({ playerMe }: any) => { 
    console.log({playerMe}) // exist
    const handleCardMove = useCallback((event: any) => {
        console.log(playerMe); // undefined
    }, [playerMe]);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleCardMove);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleCardMove);
    }, [hndleCardMove]); // Add dependency 

    return null;
};
```

Try to Add dependency on `useEffect()`